# How to export a list of all users that have access to reports from a Power BI Workspace?

Tags: powershell, powerbi, powerbi-rest-api

I am trying to audit Power BI reports and datasets to see who have access to which reports. Is there an API that allows to do so?

Ideally, my output file should have at least three columns: report, user, level of access

Is it possible to get this type of data?

I have tried using PowerShell's MicrosoftPowerBiMgmt module. It allows to list my reports and datasets but doesn't show the users who have access to reports/datasets.

For instance,
`Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url 'groups/<WORKSPACE_ID>/reports/<REPORT_ID>' -Method Get`
returns some metadata about the report but shows no users or subscriptions.

Comment: Looks like you can get the permission list from [the endpoint `admin/reports/<REPORT_ID>/users`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/reports-get-report-users-as-admin)